# Redirect child term to first page under it in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to do the following in a functions.php file?

I have the following URL structure:

```
hxxp://domain.com/custom-post-type-slug/parent-term-slug/child-term-slug/page-slug/
```

Directly under the parent term there are no pages, only child terms.

Is there a way to redirect the 'root' of the child term to the first post belonging to that same child term?

```
hxxp://domain.com/custom-post-type-slug/parent-term-slug/child-term-slug/
```

needs to redirect to:

```
hxxp://domain.com/custom-post-type-slug/parent-term-slug/child-term-slug/page-slug/
```

Comment: Could you not on the template that loads the parent term (is it an archive.php etc... page?) check to see if it is a parent term and if so redirect to the page slug? Or for a better user experience have that parent term page list all the pages within in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok my friend what you want is possible... quite strange request but possible.

```
add_action('wp', 'get_first_child');

function get_first_child() {
    global $wp_query;

    if($wp_query->queried_object_id){
        $args = array(
            'post_parent' => $wp_query->queried_object_id,
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'order'=> 'ASC',
            'post_status' => 'published' 
        );
        $post = get_children($args);
        //here I test if there is more than one child.. if yes I stop here if you want it to keep going just remove this
        $post = (count($post) > 1) ? null : reset($post);

        if($post->guid){
            wp_redirect( $post->guid, 301 );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

### So what I do here?

All I do is get all children related to the main post that you are and reset it to the first on the line if there are more than 1 child.

Then I just get his guid and redirect it using 301.

Tadã... magic was done!

Hope that is what you wanted :)

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Have nice day :-)